# Cookies are not working in QWebView

Tags: qtwebkit

When I load an Url using the load method, like this:

```
load(QUrl("http://www.foo.com"));
```

Cookies work correctly with no problems. However, when I load the content using the setHtml method, like this:

```
setHtml(htmlCode, QUrl("http://www.foo.com));
```

The website indicates that cookies aren’t enabled in my browser. I wonder if this is a known issue, and whether there’s a way to have cookies working for the setHtml method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are from HTTP protocol, not part of HTML. You need a http server embedded, Take a look at this [project](https://github.com/nikhilm/qhttpserver)